# Change the current locale

Tags: localization, control-panel, language

Can I change the current locale?

I've set up a standard site, using CRAFT client version (one language). Apparently Craft installs the en_us as the primary language. Content is added (in Dutch) and now some months later the client decides to upgrade to Craft PRO and move to a multilingual site adding an additional locale. As en_us was the primary one nl_nl is added as the next locale.

However all Dutch content was added in the (old) en_us locale. Is there a way to swap this? Change the en_us to nl_nl while keeping the Dutch content in place?

Comment: Why swap, they should be identical now?

Comment: Right. For entries that's true, but this site contains a lot of matrix entries and there it don't work that way.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it still doesn't copy Matrix content.